# CVX-esque convex optimization in R?

Tags: r, optimization, convex-optimization

I need to solve (many times, for lots of data, alongside a bunch of other things) what I think boils down to a [second order cone program](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/socp.html). It can be succinctly expressed in [CVX](https://cvxr.com/cvx/) something like this:

```
cvx_begin
    variable X(2000);
    expression MX(2000);
    MX = M * X;
    minimize( norm(A * X - b) + gamma * norm(MX, 1) )
  subject to
    X >= 0
    MX((1:500) * 4 - 3) == MX((1:500) * 4 - 2)
    MX((1:500) * 4 - 1) == MX((1:500) * 4)
cvx_end
```

The data lengths and equality constraint patterns shown are just arbitrary values from some test data, but the general form will be much the same, with two objective terms -- one minimizing error, the other encouraging sparsity -- and a large number of equality constraints on the elements of a transformed version of the optimization variable (itself constrained to be non-negative).

This seems to work pretty nicely, much better than my previous approach, which fudges the constraints something rotten. The trouble is that everything else around this is happening in R, and it would be quite a nuisance to have to port it over to Matlab. So is doing this in R viable, and if so how?

This really boils down to two separate questions:

1) Are there any good R resources for this? As far as I can tell from the [CRAN task page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html), the SOCP package options are [CLSCOP](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CLSOCP/index.html) and [DWD](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DWD/index.html), which includes an SOCP solver as an adjunct to its classifier. Both have similar but fairly opaque interfaces and are a bit thin on documentation and examples, which brings us to:

2) What's the best way of representing the above problem in the constraint block format used by these packages? The CVX syntax above hides a lot of tedious mucking about with extra variables and such, and I can just see myself spending *weeks* trying to get this right, so any tips or pointers to nudge me in the right direction would be very welcome...

Comment: Reformulating the problem (introducing slack variables 
to remove the L^1 norm and transform the L^2 norm into a cone constraint)
is relatively easy:
replace the L^1 norm of `M %*% x` with `y-z` 
and add the constraints `y >= 0`, `z >= 0`;
replace the L^2 norm of `A %*% x - b`
with `t` 
and add the constraints
`t >= sqrt( t(u) %*% u )`,
`u = A %*% x - b`.
Most of those transformations could even be 
[automated](http://zoonek.free.fr/blosxom/R/2012-06-01_Optimization.html), 
as with CVX, 
but for a simple problem like that, it is probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: However, the input format 
of `DWD::sqlp` or `CLSOCP::socp` is undocumented:
you are told which argument contains the constraints, but not how they are encoded...
You could try to contact the authors of those packages,
to have more information about the encoding of the constraints.
You could also look at the `Rcsdp` package: 
it addresses a larger class of problems (semi-definite programs),
the inputs are documented, 
but transforming your problem into the desired form will not be that straightforward...

Comment: @Vincent Thanks, that is helpful. (And that's quite a blog post!) `DWD::sqlp` looks to be modelled on SDPT3, so it might be possible to clarify the inputs by comparison.

Comment: I'm the author of CLSOCP.  There's a document on my github account that explains the input format in more detail: https://github.com/jcrudy/CLSOCP/blob/master/CLSOCP/inst/doc/manual.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find the R package [CVXfromR](http://bscb.cornell.edu/~bien/cvxfromr.html) useful.  This lets you pass an optimization problem to CVX from R and returns the solution to R.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the short answer to this question is: there's really no very satisfactory way to handle this in R. I have ended up doing the relevant parts in Matlab with some awkward fudging between the two systems, and will probably migrate everything to Matlab eventually. (My current approach predates the answer posted by user2439686. In practice my problem would be equally awkward using CVXfromR, but it does look like a useful package in general, so I'm going to accept that answer.)

R resources for this are pretty thin on the ground, but the [blog post by Vincent Zoonekynd](http://zoonek.free.fr/blosxom/R/2012-06-01_Optimization.html) that he mentioned in the comments is definitely worth reading.

The SOCP solver contained within the R package DWD is ported from the Matlab solver [SDPT3](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~mattohkc/sdpt3.html) (minus the SDP parts), so the programmatic interface is basically the same. However, at least in my tests, it runs a lot slower and pretty much falls over on problems with a few thousand vars+constraints, whereas SDPT3 solves them in a few seconds. (I haven't done a completely fair comparison on this, because CVX does some nifty transformations on the problem to make it more efficient, while in R I'm using a pretty naive definition, but still.)

Another possible alternative, especially if you're eligible for an academic license, is to use the commercial [Mosek](http://www.mosek.com/) solver, which has an R interface package [Rmosek](http://rmosek.r-forge.r-project.org/). I have yet to try this, but may give it a go at some point.

(As an aside, the other solver bundled with CVX, SeDuMi, fails completely on the same problem; the CVX authors aren't kidding when they suggest trying multiple solvers. Also, in a significant subset of cases, SDTP3 has to switch from Cholesky to LU decomposition, which makes the processing orders of magnitude slower, with only very marginal improvement in the objective compared to the pre-LU steps. I've found it worth reducing the requested precision to avoid this, but YMMV.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new alternative: [CVXR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CVXR/index.html), which comes from the same people.
 There is a [website](https://cvxr.rbind.io/), a [paper](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/cvxr_paper.html) and a [github project](https://github.com/anqif/CVXR).

Disciplined Convex Programming seems to be growing in popularity observing [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org) (Python) and [Convex.jl](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/Convex.jl) (Julia), again, backed by the same people.